# How to determine if passing an argument to a function call will do a move, a copy, a ref or a mut ref?

Tags: rust, ownership

> I am in my first days on rust, coming from php

I am developing some basic console programs to acquire confidence with ownership.

Is there a way to determine if passing an argument to a function call will do a move, a copy, a ref or a mut ref?

> I am referring to *struct*s only, defined by myself, for now.
>
> I am referring to functions not returning values. This is a whole new topic for me

For what I can understand now

### `mystruct: &mut StructureOfMine`

is explicitly a mutable ref, so if in the function I alter a field of mystruct, it will be reflected outside

### `mystruct: &StructureOfMine`

is explicitly a non mutable ref, so in the function I cannot alter fields of mystruct

### `mystruct: StructureOfMine`

`mystruct` is moved if `StructureOfMine` is not implementing Copy. I can alter `mystruct`, but the caller cannot use mystruct anymore.

`mystruct` is copyed if `StructureOfMine` is implementing Copy. I can alter `mystruct`; the  caller use its original copy of mystruct but changes to this copy are not reversed into the original one

### Questions

Can you confirm / redact what I understood of these cases?

Is there a way to determine if something has been copied or moved ?

Comment: it seems like you answered your own question, [`Copy` types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#implementors) are copied, all other types are moved. `&` is a immutable reference, `&mut` is a mutable reference.

Comment: There is no way to determine if something has been copied or moved, because it doesn't make a difference for anybody; neither for the function that it has been passed to, nor for the outer function.

Comment: Additional context, references are `Copy`

Comment: @Finomnis: the difference is big for outer, calling, function, because in case of a move it cannot do anything other to the parameter because of moved ownership...

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley, please expand, I didn't understand

Comment: @realtebo The way you "figure it out" is by programming it and seeing if it compiles. If it compiles, it's a copy, because using a moved object later is a compilation error. You can't cause undefined behaviour in Rust, it's all compiler errors.

Comment: Maybe you are coming from a C++ background, where you have to actively make sure you don't re-use moved objects; This is not a concern in Rust as it is literally impossible to do this by accident.

Comment: @Finomnis, no experience in c++; i am learning rust exactly because I don't know c and c++ and I want to learn something <> php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BlackBeans already answered most of your question, I will talk about "how do I detect a Copy vs a Move".

It's not really important which one is actually used in the end. Rust figures this out internally.

The only difference for the programmer is that you cannot use a moved object after it is moved away. This isn't a big concern, however, because this is not something the programmer has to ensure by himself; it is literally a compiler error to do this wrong. This is the beauty of the borrow checker.

Here, look at the following code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct StructWithCopy;

fn take_object(obj: StructWithCopy) {
    println!("Taken: {:?} (Address: {:p})", obj, &obj);
}

fn main() {
    let obj = StructWithCopy;
    take_object(obj);
    println!("Original: {:?} (Address: {:p})", obj, &obj);
}
```

```
Taken: StructWithCopy (Address: 0x7fff9ced8478)
Original: StructWithCopy (Address: 0x7fff9ced8508)
```

Here, a copy is used; simply *because* you are able to access the object after passing it to the function.

If the object wouldn't be copyable, this would cause a compiler error:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct StructWithoutCopy;

fn take_object(obj: StructWithoutCopy) {
    println!("Taken: {:?} (Address: {:p})", obj, &obj);
}

fn main() {
    let obj = StructWithoutCopy;
    take_object(obj);
    println!("Original: {:?} (Address: {:p})", obj, &obj);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `obj`
  --> src/main.rs:11:48
   |
9  |     let obj = StructWithoutCopy;
   |         --- move occurs because `obj` has type `StructWithoutCopy`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
10 |     take_object(obj);
   |                 --- value moved here
11 |     println!("Original: {:?} (Address: {:p})", obj, &obj);
   |                                                ^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

This is the beauty of programming in Rust; you can be confident that when your code compiles, there is no undefined behavior in it, like double free, using uninitialized memory, buffer overflows, etc.

Don't think about it too much, just enjoy the confidence your compiler provides :)

Answer (score 2):

You've understood the cases, but it seems like you are missing the big picture, because they all are handled by a single, very simple rule, which is: when you pass a value in a function, it is moved, which means it is copied to a new location where the function expects it. In addition, Rust's ownership model now assumes the variable is owned by the called function, not anymore by the caller. Keep in mind that this rule applies to *any* type. Let's see how it applies to the particular cases your have mentioned.

#### Types that implement `Copy`

Let's start with a fundamental one. `Copy` is just a marker trait that says to the compiler "forget about the ownership transferal", that is, if I move a value, it doesn't mean I don't own it anymore (at least, from the ownership point of view; `Copy` also implies other things).

It's actually quite natural: assume I have a number, and I give you that number (by copying it, which is the only way to physically move memory around). Does it mean *my* version of the number gets invalidated? No. Which is why all numerical types in Rust implement `Copy`.

A type that doesn't implement `Copy`, on the other hand, is for example a vector. This is because a vector is, roughly speaking, a pointer to an area of the memory that is also "owned" by whomever owns the vector, and that gets freed when the vector is dropped. This means that, when I move a vector to you, I only copy that pointer, **not the whole allocated memory** (which shouldn't move anyways). This invalidates *my* version of the vector because not doing so would mean that the data allocated in memory, which is owned by the fat pointer, has now two owners (which is not allowed by Rust's ownership model). This is why `Vec<_>: !Copy`. *Note that if you wanted to also copy the whole allocate memory, in order to keep my version valid, you'd have to explicitly `clone` it, which is possible because `Vec<T>: Clone` if `T: Clone`.*

#### Borrows

Now, the case of borrows is very simply. For any type `T`, `&T: Copy`. It's that simple! When I pass a borrow of data I own, I have first to create a borrow myself (which I own), then I pass it, which simply means copying the pointer, and my borrow is still valid.

Note that this is possible because it's impossible (at least, let's assume it is for the sake of simplicity) to modify a value behind a borrow, which makes the `&T: Copy` sound.

In addition, I can't myself access the owned data if there is still a chance of someone having a borrow of it somewhere.

#### Mutable borrows

A mutable borrow is pretty much like a borrow, except it doesn't implement `Copy` (nor `Clone`, so you can't either explicitly `clone` it). This means that when you first create a mutable borrow, which you own, and then pass, it is still copied, but you version gets invalidated (because you gave ownership).

In addition, you can't create a borrow (mutable or not) or access the owned data is the mutable borrow is still around.